# formencode Schema add fields dynamically

Tags: python, forms, formencode

Let's take, for example, a User `Schema` where the site admin sets the number of requested phone numbers:

```
class MySchema(Schema):
    name = validators.String(not_empty=True)
    phone_1 = validators.PhoneNumber(not_empty=True)
    phone_2 = validators.PhoneNumber(not_empty=True)
    phone_3 = validators.PhoneNumber(not_empty=True)
    ...
```

Somehow I thought I could simply do:

```
class MySchema(Schema):
    name = validators.String(not_empty=True)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        requested_phone_numbers = Session.query(...).scalar()
        for n in xrange(requested_phone_numbers):
            key = 'phone_{0}'.format(n)
            kwargs[key] = validators.PhoneNumber(not_empty=True)
        Schema.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

since I read in [FormEncode docs](http://formencode.org/Validator.html#other-validator-usage):

> Validators use instance variables to store their customization
>   information. You can use either subclassing or normal instantiation to
>   set these.

and `Schema` is called in docs as a Compound Validator and is a subclass of `FancyValidator` so I guessed it's correct.

But this does not work: simply added `phone_n` are ignored and only `name` is required.

**Update:**

Also I tried both overriding `__new__` and `__classinit__` before asking with no success...

Answer (score 5):

i had the same problem, i found a solution here:
http://markmail.org/message/m5ckyaml36eg2w3m

all the thing is to use the add_field method of schema in youre **init** method

```
class MySchema(Schema):
    name = validators.String(not_empty=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        requested_phone_numbers = Session.query(...).scalar()
        for n in xrange(requested_phone_numbers):
            key = 'phone_{0}'.format(n)
            self.add_field(key, validators.PhoneNumber(not_empty=True))
```

i don't think there's a need to call the parent init

Comment: Yes! Thank you! This just solved my problem after over an hour of searching for solutions.